# scrollView does not display all the content top, and drawn too many of his bottom income

Tags: android

I tried to search everywhere for what I got stuck on it here, the issue is the scrollViewI have two problems with the scrollView:The first problem;The scrollView not give all of the content that has,I tried to add the following line: android: fillViewport = "true"But it did not help  Second problem;Full content shown leaving the space at the end and ends at the end of scrollView content

```
enter code here     

 <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="90"
        android:padding="15dp" 
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view" 
        >


          <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
              android:orientation="vertical"

               >
    ....
```

Thanks to those who could help me...

Comment: Thank you very much your answer really helped me
My mistake was that I put this line:
android: layout_gravity = "center_vertical"
In linearout And that made me the problem (it's really just introduced the center and beyond)
Thank you searched for the problem and realized it :)

Comment: I re-posted my comment as an answer. Now you can accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to set `layout_weight` in your `ScrollView`?
If not remove this line or set it's value to 1.

Also change the `layout_width` & `layout_height` to `fill_parent` in the child view.

Comment: You definitely don't want to set the `layout_height` of a `ScrollView` child to `fill_parent`. Instead you should set `android:fillViewport="true"` in the `ScrollView` itself. Also, depending on the siblings of the `ScrollView`, changing the layout weight from 90 to 1 (or eliminating it) may be very wrong.

Comment: "android:fillViewport="true"" is already in the "ScrollView", can you please explain your self more clearly about changing the weight?

Comment: If the `ScrollView` is part of a larger layout, then OP may be trying to split the screen so 90% goes to the `ScrollView` and 10% goes to something else. I know that `android:fillViewport="true"` was already set. I was just pointing out the `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` (or `"match_parent"`) is almost always wrong for the child of a `ScrollView`.

Comment: From the original post I understand that the `ScrollView` is not displayed on the whole screen, that's why I noticed the `weight` tag. But thank you.

Comment: I have to assign this line layout_weight that it shapes me the page in such a way that I have only part of a page in scrollView and the entireAnd I did not understand what you meant by the words "in the child view." What is the child and what is the father?Definitions of width and length are:In scrollView:android: layout_width = "fill_parent"android: layout_height = "fill_parent"In linearout:android: layout_width = "match_parent"android: layout_height = "wrap_content"

Answer (score 0):

I first posted this as a comment, but since it solved the problem, I'll post it as an answer instead.

The attribute `android:orientation` does not apply to `ScrollView`; you should remove it. Also, you should remove the `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` attribute in the child view; it's not appropriate for the child of a `ScrollView`.